# Windows CMD equilvance of this command

Tags: command-line, cmd, environment-variables, vagrant, regedit

I'm following this guide here: 
https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack

In setting up a edx server.  I've done this on Cywgin, now I am trying to replicate the process on Windows Command Line.

I come to this command, which is setting the environment for Vagrant

```
export VAGRANT_MOUNT_BASE=$PWD
```

What would be the equivalence in Windows?  I've seen multiple ways through internet searches such as regedit, but I'm not too clear what is the right one.

Comment: Hint: you need to set an environment variable.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't assume that `export` is self-explanatory. Say what it does...

Comment: So the setx command would work for setting the enviroment?

I'm assuming that the $ means that the pwd is the variable, so,
`setx $pwd = vagrant_mount_base` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command should do the trick:

```
set "VAGRANT_MOUNT_BASE=%CD%"
```

The shell variable `$PWD` refers to the current working directory. `%CD%` does the same thing under `CMD.EXE`. The bash command `export` makes the variable visible as an environment variable for Vagrant. Under Windows variables set up with the `set` command are visible by default.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for should be:

```
SET VAGRANT_MOUNT_BASE=%CD%
```